# Probability that a random polynomial has a linear factor?

Tags: probability, finite-fields

What is the probability that a random degree $d$ polynomial in $\Bbb F_p[x]$ has a linear factor (root in $\Bbb F_p$) for cases $d>p$ and $d<p$? Lower bound is $\frac1p$ but definitely seems much higher?

Comment: What is a "random polynomial"? If the coefficients are picked randomly, then what are their distributions?

Comment: You have C polynomials of degree d pick one uniformly.

Comment: Related: https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/11/10/small-factors-in-random-polynomials-over-a-finite-field/, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1532055/